# Property 'then' does not exist on type 'IPayload<T>'

Tags: reactjs, promise, jhipster

I have an application generated using JHipster 6.x with React JS as UI. In many screens I am fetching data using redux methods like

Method:

```
export const getStudentsByCriteria: ICrudSearchAction<IStudent> = (query, page, size, sort) => ({
  type: ACTION_TYPES.SEARCH_STUDENTS,
  payload: axios.get<IStudent>(`${apiUrl}?${query}${sort ? `&page=${page}&size=${size}&sort=${sort}` : ''}`)
});
```

Call:

```
(this.props.getStudentsByCriteria('classSectionId.equals=' + classSectionId, 0, 50, "firstName,asc") as IPayload<IStudent>).payload.then((response) => { ... }
```

It's been working quite fine but all of sudden I started getting error: *TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'IPayload | ((dispatch: any) => IPayload)'.
Property 'then' does not exist on type 'IPayload'*

Simply calling .then gives compile error in MS Code but works locally without any issue however  won't allow to build war because of compile errors

```
(this.props.getStudentsByCriteria('classSectionId.equals=' + classSectionId, 0, 50, "firstName,asc").then((response) => { ... }
```

This should return IPayload and IPayload.payload.then ... must work. It's been working, it's pretty strange that it stopped working all of a sudden.

Comment: Maybe you had an `await` in there before?

Comment: I didn't. I didn't change anything in the code. Yeah a few components were added in the project

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by converting returned object to Promise as given in below code:

```
(this.props.getStudentsByCriteria('classSectionId.equals=' + classSectionId, 0, 50, "rollNo,firstName") as unknown as Promise<IStudent[]>).then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        sectionStudents: (response as any).value.data
      });
    });
```

Had to use ... as unknown as Promise. VS Code shows response type as IStudent[] but it gives error on runtime when I try to call map function. (map is not supported for IStudent[]). Since response type at compile is IStudent[], it doesn't have value property and gives error, therefore it had to be converted to 'any' to get value.data. Debugging the code unraveled this.

Why this code stopped returning IPayload is still a mystery for me.